# How to allow web-component-tester to run tests stored with my components

Tags: polymer, web-component-tester

I am experimenting with the framework to build an SPA using polymer. This will include a large number of custom elements at various levels in the overall application hierarchy.  I would like to use web-component-tester to run the module tests on them.

web-component-tester seems to be opinionated about where the tests will be stored - in a separate test directory, where it will run all files found.

I am of an opposite opinion.  I would like to store tests in the same directory as the element definition.  I would like to differentiate tests by naming them xxx.test.html (or possibly xxx.test.js).  I also want to run different "sets" of tests controlled by gulp some of which will be watching for changes and then running the tests (for the app side of my project) and some of which will be elements that use core-ajax to unit test my server side scripts.  These will more than likely be in a totally different directory hierarchy (my dist directory) and will be served by a proper web server.

I "think" the "suite" config option wct-conf.js file in my project root might be how I can define this, or alternatively a wct command with some file globs.  Unfortunately web-component-tester's README is somewhat confusing on any detail and when you have your own web server it says "You'll need to save WCT's `browser.js` in order to go this route."  What does that mean?

Can someone enlighten me on how can get WCT to run each of the elements/**/*.test.html files as its own "suite" ( I actually intend to use describe, it format - but I assume I still need to use the term suite).

Can someone also explain what I need to do the browser.js when I have my own web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran some experiments and did a bit of debugging with node-inspector.  Firstly, the command line overwrites the suites parameter in the config file

`wct app/elements**/*.test.html`

does find all my module tests if I have them stored with the elements and ignores the contents of the wct.conf.js file's suites parameter.

also putting the same value (ie app/elements/**/*.test.html)  in the wct-conf.js file for the suite parameter does the same job.  In fact in this mode, `gulp test:local`
Also works correctly

So to run different tests for module and distribution, I just need to set up for `wct.conf.js` for my module tests, and set up gulp to run a command line with the correct location of my test file

I still haven't understood the instructions for running with your own web server.

Comment: So you are running a different file glob for each gulp task? i.e. app/elements/first/**/*.test.html, app/elements/second/**/*.test.html

Comment: This was a long time ago, and my structure has changed - but I didn't run different globs. The '**' in the definition automatically covers the multiple level hierarchy, although I never got to a point where I needed it.  My structure has changed, I have about 100 custom elements, all in the same directory, with the test suites in a separate directory ("test") and supporting files in a "mocks" directory